# getMimeTypeFromExtension for EPUB returns null

Tags: android, epub, mediastore

I am trying to get the MIME type for an epubfile, which, as listen on Wikipedia is `application/epub+zip`. However, the method is returning null.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

String[] projection = null;
String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                        + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_NONE;
String[] selectionArgs = null; // there is no ? in selection so null here
String sortOrder = null; // unordered
String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("epub"); //this line here returns null
// String mimeType = "application/epub+zip" this returns null too. 
String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{ mimeType };
Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, sortOrder);
```

Is there any other method to import epub files? It is possible, because there are apps that do that. (Moon Reader)

Comment: [epub was added Thu Dec 11 13:07:19 2014](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+log/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java) ...  so every android version before this would obviously return null ...

Comment: Can you confirmthe android version?

Comment: And obviously, how do I make this work for older devices?

Comment: obviously you have to get real file name and check the extention ...

Comment: I already know the extension. That is why the above code is what it is.

Comment: instead `mime_type='mimetype/check'` query for `file_name like '%.epub'`

Comment: Can you elaborate that using code?

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

    // every column, although that is huge waste, you probably need
    // BaseColumns.DATA (the path) only.
            String[] projection = null;

    // exclude media files, they would be here also.
            String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_NONE;
            String[] selectionArgs = null; // there is no ? in selection so null here

            Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, projection, selection,selectionArgs,null);
            int NumberOfPDFS =cur.getCount();
            cl(Integer.toString(NumberOfPDFS));


            cur.moveToFirst();
            while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                if(cur.getString(1).lastIndexOf(".epub")!=-1){
                    //do whatever.
                }

                cur.moveToNext();
            }
            cur.close();

        }
```